# Bound on the pdf of a function of a normal random vector

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X\sim N(0, \Sigma)$ for some positive definite matrix $\Sigma$ and $f(x)=\lVert\max\{X-a, 0\}-\min\{X+b,0\}\rVert$ for some nonnegative vectors $a$ and $b$ (here $\max$ and $\min$ are taken element-wise). Can we bound
$$
\sup_{x>0}\mathsf{P}\{x<f(X)\le x+\varepsilon\}
$$
by $\sup_{x>0}\mathsf{P}\{x<\lVert X\rVert\le x+\varepsilon\}$? Note that the distribution of $f(X)$ has an atom at zero when $a,b\ne 0$.